# How to know with java whether file is corrupted (readable) or not?

Tags: java, file, jakarta-ee

I have web application where person can upload any pdf via FTP. After pdf file get uploaded I perform certain operations over that pdf.

But the problem here is, while uploading the PDF via FTP sometimes connection breaks up in between and the pdf uploaded is not complete (act like corrupted one). When I try to open that document in arobat reader it gives message '*There was an error opening the document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired*'.

Now before starting processing over PDF, I want to check whether pdf uploaded is readable means no corrupted.

Do java provide any API for that, or there is any method to check whether file is corrupted or not.

Comment: Use `MD5SUM` to make local hash and after uploading make remote hash and compare them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We have [***iText API***](http://itextpdf.com/) in Java to work on PDF files.

To check if a PDF file is valid to load and read, use `com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader`.
If the file is corrupted, an exception like `com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException`, is thrown.

**Sample code snippet**:

```
...  
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;  
...  
try {  
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader( pathToUploadedPdfFile );  

    String textFromPdfFilePageOne = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage( pdfReader, 1 ); 
    System.out.println( textFromPdfFilePageOne );
}  
catch ( Exception e ) {  
    // handle exception  
}
```

In case of uploaded but corrupted files, you may face the following error:

```
com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: Rebuild failed:   
  trailer not found.; Original message: PDF startxref not found.
```

*Note*: To produce such an exception, try saving a pdf file from net, but abort it in the middle.
Use it to load through *above code snippet* and check if it is loaded safe.

You can find detailed examples on iText API at

> [**Use Case Examples of iText PDF | iText**](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/examples).

Comment: How to know if the bitmap/image file is corrupted?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? And how do you want it using with `itext`?

Comment: I just need to know that is there any way to find out the Stored image is corrupt or not? [android, java]

Comment: AFAIK, there is no such thing to check if an image is corrupted. Even if part of the image is stored. That can be opened in any image viewer and it shows the stored image portion.

Comment: This answer at [*How to determine if a photo is corrupted?*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5139214/767881) may be useful for you.