# How to check if a PDF file is corrupted or not in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, pdf-generation

I am working on an application where I need to download multiple PDF files from the server and save them and on the print all command in my application I will merge all the PDFs and show print preview.

But the issue is while merging I am facing few files that are corrupted due to not saving correctly or are corrupted in general.

How can I check if the saved file is corrupt or not?

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477327/how-to-know-with-java-whether-file-is-corrupted-readable-or-not

Comment: Which PDF library do you want to use for the task? What kind of corruption are you after?