# Check for corrupted image in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, security, upload

I try to upload an image file which is corrupted by some HTML and script tag.

What I did was I opened a file in Notepad and entered some HTML and a script tag into it, then uploaded it.

At the time of uploading, I want to check that the image hasn't been edited or corrupted.

Comment: Suppose,  first i edit image, and then upload, then what getimagesize() can do.

Answer (score 0):

You can try some things, but with certain file formats (example: BMP, JPEG to some extent) *only a human can ultimately decide if the file is OK or corrupted*.

The simplest test is to simply load the file into a corresponding object (TJpegImage, TPngObject, etc). If you get an exception while loading you've surely got a corrupted file.

Unfortunately if no exception is raised you can't really say the file is not corrupted.

Check Answer On Stackoverflow [**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138797/how-to-determine-if-a-photo-is-corrupted#answer-5139214)

Comment: Thanks for reply