# Detecting if a file is an image in Python

Tags: python, image

Is there any general way to detect if a file is a image (jpg, bmp, png, etc...)

Or is making a list of the file extensions and doing a one-by-one comparison the only way?

Comment: According to the standard python file types http://docs.python.org/c-api/concrete.html image file isn't standard, so I suppose some external module will be required.

Comment: Use the `imghdr` module. See [How to check if a file is a valid image file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889333/how-to-check-if-a-file-is-a-valid-image-file)

Comment: My solution: `try: Image.open(img_path).format in ["JPEG", "PNG", "GIF", "BMP"]; except: print(img_path)`

Answer (score 28):

Assuming:

```
>>> files = {"a_movie.mkv", "an_image.png", "a_movie_without_extension", "an_image_without_extension"}
```

And they are proper movie and image files in script folder.

You can use builtin mimetypes module, but it won't work without extensions.

```
>>> import mimetypes
>>> {file: mimetypes.guess_type(file) for file in files}
{'a_movie_without_extension': (None, None), 'an_image.png': ('image/png', None), 'an_image_without_extension': (None, None), 'a_movie.mkv': (None, None)}
```

Or call the unix command `file`. This works without extensions, but not in Windows:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> def find_mime_with_file(path):
...     command = "/usr/bin/file -i {0}".format(path)
...     return subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].split()[1]
... 
>>> {file: find_mime_with_file(file) for file in files}
{'a_movie_without_extension': 'application/octet-stream;', 'an_image.png': 'image/png;', 'an_image_without_extension': 'image/png;', 'a_movie.mkv': 'application/octet-stream;'}
```

Or you try to open it with PIL, and check for errors, but needs PIL installed:

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> def check_image_with_pil(path):
...     try:
...         Image.open(path)
...     except IOError:
...         return False
...     return True
... 
>>> {file: check_image_with_pil(file) for file in files}
{'a_movie_without_extension': False, 'an_image.png': True, 'an_image_without_extension': True, 'a_movie.mkv': False}
```

Or, for simplicity, as you say, just check extensions, it's the best way I think.

```
>>> extensions = {".jpg", ".png", ".gif"} #etc
>>> {file: any(file.endswith(ext) for ext in extensions) for file in files}
{'a_movie_without_extension': False, 'an_image.png': True, 'an_image_without_extension': False, 'a_movie.mkv': False}
```

Comment: +1 noting for others that the use of `file` or option two worked best for my use case where I was crawling retrieving images that were returned w/o an extension and need to save them as either .jpg/.png

Comment: There is also an easy way to this...."if 'file' in request.files:" try this out if there is file then it will return true..

Answer (score 2):

You should use a library for this. Note that extension != file type, because you can change the extension to a .jpg file, open it with paint and paint will interpret it like a jpeg (for example). You should check [How to find the mime type of a file in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43580/how-to-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-in-python).

Comment: This was already mentioned  - this should be a comment, not an answer