# django rest framework saving base64 file

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

how can i handle base64 file field in django rest framework. I am using django extra fields but its not working.

serializers.py

```
from drf_extra_fields.fields import Base64FileField

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    file  = Base64FileField()
    class Meta:
        model = Product

        fields = (
                    "name",
                    "file"
                )



class ProductApi(SerializerMixin, APIView):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = ProductSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            return Response("Valid serializer", status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(
                            serializer.errors, 
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
                        )
```

but when i tried this i am getting this error.

```
Exception Value: 'NotImplementedType' object is not callable
```

How can i save base64 file in the database using django rest framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in [drf-extra-fields docs](https://github.com/Hipo/drf-extra-fields#base64filefield):

> You have to provide **your own full implementation** of this class. You have to implement file validation in `get_file_extension` method and set `ALLOWED_TYPES` list.

You use the default `Base64FileField`, that's why you receive:

```
Exception Value: 'NotImplementedType' object is not callable
```

In this case, you need to extend the default `Base64FileField` and make your custom field, along with validation method `get_file_extension` and set `ALLOWED_TYPES` list as a property.

An example directly from the docs:

```
class PDFBase64File(Base64FileField):
    ALLOWED_TYPES = ['pdf']

    def get_file_extension(self, filename, decoded_file):
        try:
            PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(io.BytesIO(decoded_file))
        except PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError as e:
            logger.warning(e)
        else:
            return 'pdf'
```

Here this is a field for `PDF` files. Then in your `ProductSerializer` you can use the new field: `file = PDFBase64FileField()`.

To support more file types, try the [`filetype`](https://github.com/h2non/filetype.py) library.

Comment: file format will be anything like docs, pdf or image . so how can i handle this

Comment: @Thameem At first, set `ALLOWED_TYPES = ('pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', ...)` and whatever extensions you want. Then, perform validations in your `get_file_extension` method. You already have PDF validation, it's up to you to implement the others.

Comment: @wencaksis could you please point me to validation of jpeg and pdf in a single method. how can i do that.

Comment: @Thameem Hope this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640605/detecting-if-a-file-is-an-image-in-python You can implement separate validation for each type and then call them all in `get_file_extension`