# Importing images from a directory (Python) to list or dictionary

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to import all the images inside a directory (the directory location is known).

```
path = /home/user/mydirectory
```

I already know a way of finding out the length of the directory.

What I'm not sure about is how I can import the images (using `PIL/Pillow`) into either a list or a dictionary, so they can be properly manipulated.

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-to-list-all-files-of-a-directory-in-python
It's a method for listing all file in a directory, from there you could just call your read image function on each.

Comment: Mike gave you a solution to find all the files - since you have all the file names, you can open them - sometimes you have to think!

Comment: hey Charles, you're pretty new here and so am I...one thing I've learned is that the easier it is for people to help you, the more feedback you'll get.  It's OK (IMHO) to not know how to program and still ask a question but to demonstrate effort by coming up with even a broken version of code will make folks happier to help. We here like examples that we can fix, not generalities! I think it's a bit mean to downvote a new user so don't be discouraged!

Comment: @AndrewBarber : With all due respoect to your moderator role, I think the question is clear (and shouldn't be on hold) - given that the question has two answers (which do similar things), and one of which has been accepted.

Comment: This question is not at all clear, and the solutions do solve the problem only to a certain degree.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

I'd start by using glob:

```
from PIL import Image
import glob
image_list = []
for filename in glob.glob('yourpath/*.gif'): #assuming gif
    im=Image.open(filename)
    image_list.append(im)
```

then do what you need to do with your list of images (image_list).

Comment: `image_list = map(Image.open, glob('your/path/*.gif'))`

Comment: A nicer solution than mine (using glob correctly), but this is more difficult to extend for other image types - unless you want a more complex regex.

Comment: both comments good. JFS: nice and compact...I would use something similar but sometimes it's easier for folks still learning python to understand something more readable, so that's what I try and deliver. Tony, yes, no matter how you slice it there will be a little bit of ugliness with accommodating for different extensions.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian `image_list = [Image.open(item) for i in [glob.glob('your/path/*.%s' % ext) for ext in ["jpg","gif","png","tga"]] for item in i]`   ;)

Comment: one more thing to note...sometimes I deal with 1,000s or 10s of 1,000s of images and to naively put them ALL into a list would be foolish.  if I iterate with a for loop it makes it easier to chunk them into batches and operate withing my RAM limits.

Comment: Is there anyway to load them in Jupyter Notebook as output? I used 'image.show()` but it only opens image using a default app.

Comment: @BowenLiu  try using matplotlib with the "%matplotlib inline" directive at the top of your notebook.  see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410042/how-to-make-ipython-notebook-matplotlib-plot-inline  for details

Comment: just to add, if your path is a network path you should do it as this: url = r"\\Documents\myimage.jpg"
    from PIL import Image
    im = Image.open(url)
    im.show()

Answer (score 48):

```
from PIL import Image
import os, os.path

imgs = []
path = "/home/tony/pictures"
valid_images = [".jpg",".gif",".png",".tga"]
for f in os.listdir(path):
    ext = os.path.splitext(f)[1]
    if ext.lower() not in valid_images:
        continue
    imgs.append(Image.open(os.path.join(path,f)))
```

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - thanks for the corrections - I would have been happy for you to have made those edits :-)

Comment: another way to test it: `if f.lower().endswith(valid_images): append` (`valid_images` should be a tuple in this case).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian : True in terms of using `endswith`, but I think it is *better* to use splitext and then compare when testing the extension of a file - it is a bit more explicit.

Comment: Related for checking if it is a valid image: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889333/how-to-check-if-a-file-is-a-valid-image-file