# Cannot read a list of pictures cv2.imread()

Tags: python, opencv, listdir

I am new in programming, and I would like to make a picture resizer with gui.
I have problems with making the gui.
I grabbed the problematic part of the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import os, backend, glob2, cv2

loaded_pics=[]
picture_read=[]
window = Tk()

browsed_dir = StringVar()

browsed_dir.set(filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir="/",title='Please select a directory'))
file_path = browsed_dir.get()#+"/"

for filename in os.listdir(file_path):
    if filename.endswith(('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.png')):
        loaded_pics.append(filename)
print(loaded_pics)

try:
    for images in loaded_pics:
        imgs = cv2.imread(images, 1)
        print(imgs)
except:
    print("ERROR")


window.destroy()
window.mainloop()
```

So, I have got a list of .png/.jpg/.bmp files,  I can print the list, but I cannot read them with cv2.imread(), when I print(imgs), I got "None"-s.

(I have not managed to make this with glob2. It is work well with current directory, but I could not make it with filedialog.)

I hope someone can help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, maybe the problem is the filepath.

Comment: I see two possibilities. Either the images cannot be read because their fileformat is not supported by opencv imread (that can happen if you save an emf file as png or so). Or you have a problem with your file- or folder name. It might happen that it contains non-ASCII characters which will not be properly interpreted.

Comment: there are a few responses here that could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26392336/importing-images-from-a-directory-python/26392492

Comment: Thank you @user1269942. The solution was [http://stackoverflow.com/a/26392490/7507462]

without 'Image.open'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are building a list of filenames in `loaded_pics`. But this doesn't include the name of the directory, `file_path`. So when you call `imread`, your image is actually located at `file_path/filename`, but you are only passing `filename`. So cv2 cannot find your file, and returns `None`.