# Load all images from a folder using PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

```
import glob
from PIL import Image 


marked = glob.iglob("D:/Users/username/Desktop/cells/Marked")

img = Image.open(marked)
img.show()
```

I am trying to create a neural network using an image dataset contained in the Folder marked. When I run the code I get the error:

```
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2547, in open
    fp.seek(0)
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'seek'
```

I do not understand what the error means, it seems to be misdirected?

Comment: [`Image.open()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open) take a single file string/path/object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to specify a wildcard at the end of your path and iterate:

```
images = []
for f in glob.iglob("D:/Users/username/Desktop/cells/Marked/*"):
    images.append(np.asarray(Image.open(f)))

images = np.array(images)
```

Comment: Downvoter, can you please give me feedback to improve this answer?

Comment: If the images have different shape the np.array(images) would fail

Answer (score 5):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26392336/importing-images-from-a-directory-python/26392490), which uses PIL.Image and glob to find all images in the folder and load them into an array.

```py
from PIL import Image
import glob
image_list = []
for filename in glob.glob('yourpath/*.gif'): #assuming gif
    im=Image.open(filename)
    image_list.append(im)
```

Comment: What are the advantages of this over @coldspeed's already accepted answer please?

Comment: Just pointing out that there is an existing answer that works just as well (also including import statements).