# How to load image using pygame.image.load()?

Tags: python, pygame

I just want to know the syntax. How do I load an image using pygame.image.load() ?
Let's take an example, I want to load an image called cat.png - and type this

```
pygame.image.load('cat.png')
```

Then, where should the image cat.png be saved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Python only searches in your current directory for files, however, if you wish to load images from a separate directory, you may find this useful:
[Importing images from a directory (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26392336/importing-images-from-a-directory-python)

For the syntax, I reccomend you refer to the documentation, here: 
https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load

```
pygame.image.load()¶
    load new image from a file
    load(filename) -> Surface
    load(fileobj, namehint="") -> Surface

Load an image from a file source. You can pass either a filename or a Python file-like object.
```

Answer (score 1):

Any images loaded directly with

```
pygame.image.load('Image Name')
```

should be saved in the same folder as the python script that is using the image