# convert image into pixel dataframe into csv file using python

Tags: python

i have folder with pictures `("C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\mypicture")`
here example of it
[8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ey9WR.jpg)
and[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGY1V.jpg)

i want convert it to pixel dataframe like this

```
  pixel1 pixel. pixel158 pixel159 pixel160 pixel161 pixel162 pixel163 pixel164 pixel165 pixel166 pixel167 pixel168 pixel169 pixel170 pixel171 pixel172
1      0      …        0      191      250      253       93        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
2      0      …       32        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
  pixel173 pixel174 pixel175 pixel176
1        0        0        0        0
2        0        0       16      179
```

Every image is represented as a single row . The greyscale of each image falls in the range [0, 255].
i do so

```
img = mpimg.imread("C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\mypicture")
img = np.ravel(img) 
df = pd.DataFrame([img])
```

but i get this error

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

How can i get desired data frame in csv file?

Comment: Please include the full traceback so we can see which line is generating the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could Use [PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.io) library to convert the image to a pixel dataframe, by getting the pixel's list from an image like this

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('image.png')

pixels = list(im.getdata())
```

this will return a list of pixels with the `(r,g,b)` values, so if you just want to get the grayscale of each pixel, just iterate the list in the second element of each value, like this

```
result = []
counter = 0
for pixel in pixels:
    counter += 1
    result.append(['pixel'+ str(counter), pixel[1]])
return (result)
```

**Output:**

```
['pixel1', 72], ['pixel2', 50], ['pixel3', 0], ['pixel4', 11], ['pixel5', 30], ['pixel6', 42], ['pixel7', 107], ['pixel8', 123], ['pixel9', 124], ['pixel10', 130]
```

Comment: im = Image.open('image.png')  Here only one picture. I have many pictures, how to show path for my folder with picture and then convert all picture to pixels?

Comment: You could try using glob https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html. Here there is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26392336/importing-images-from-a-directory-python