# How to Convert the data of all images in a folder into a csv file?

Tags: python

I am currently working on a project. For this I have taken pictures and saved them in a folder.

The created image files are always called `0a0e69f4-c3c9-11eb-908c.jpg`. Now I want to convert the created images into a CSV file. I read the pictures with cv2.

```
image = cv2.imread("a0e69f4-c3c9-11eb-908c.jpg")
```

My question is how can I output the complete images to a csv file with a run method? If I manually enter the path of each image in the ``image = cv2.imread("Output_Images")``` it works. Since there are too many images, I want to convert the complete images into a CSV file with one run click. How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing images from a directory (Python) to list or dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26392336/importing-images-from-a-directory-python-to-list-or-dictionary)

Comment: Thats what we use functions for, if you repeat a process over and over. your parameter is the folder. then iterate over all files in that folder, and for each file do things (in your case converting them)

Comment: Thank you. How can I make it so that it only takes over certain pictures, e.g. I have three pictures called ``Test_1, Test_2, Test_3``. There are also other pictures in the folder, but they are called something else. I only want these three pictures to be transferred to a csv file and all other pictures to be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a for loop and iterate over images in the directory:

```
import glob
for file in glob.iglob('Output_Images/*.jpg'):
        image = cv2.imread(file)
```

Answer (score 1):

`os.listdir('Output_Images')` will give you a list of all the files in the directory, then use string concatenation or `os.path.join()` to build the paths dynamically via a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

This python code converts jpg image folder to csv file.
Well done

```
import os

from PIL import Image

import numpy as np

def ListofFiles(Dir):
    Files = []

    for root, dir_name, file_name in os.walk(Dir): 

#root store address till directory, dir_name stores directory name # file_name 
stores file name

        for name in file_name:

            fullName = os.path.join(root, name)

            Files.append(fullName)

    return Files

FileList = ListofFiles('C:/..../..../your_folder') # <----path

pixels=[]

for file in FileList:

    Im = Image.open(file)

    pixels.append(list(Im.getdata()))

from numpy import savetxt

pixels_arr=np.asarray(pixels)

print((pixels_arr.shape))

#savetxt('numbers.csv', pixels_arr, delimiter=',')

np.savetxt('pred1.csv', pixels_arr, fmt='%s')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def load_img(name):
    img = plt.imread(name)
    return img
images = [load_img(im) for im in os.listdir(Path)]
```

Comment: Please format your answer

Comment: What is `Path` here? And note that code is a lot more helpful when accompanied with an explanation. Please read [answer].

Comment: Please elaborate your answer a little: Why does it solve the problem? What is different to other answers?