# Get images from images folder within pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working on a game with pygame and I have the following directory for it:
[image]

As you can see, I have an images folder in the package.
Now I'm struggling, to get the image with the path "JumpnRun/images/player/jumper-1.png" from within the path "JumpnRun/Player/Player.py".
I tried to get that image using the following code:

```py
self.image:pygame.Surface = pygame.image.load(str(Path("..") / "images" / "player" / "jumper-1.png")).convert_alpha()
```

But this doesn't seem to work and I get the error "FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory."
Any ideas on that?

Comment: have answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26392336/importing-images-from-a-directory-python-to-list-or-dictionary

Answer (score 1):

So, to get the image with `pygame.image.load` function, you should do in this way: `carImg = pygame.image.load('image.png')`.

To find out more, I recommand you to check out this link : https://pythonprogramming.net/displaying-images-pygame/

The code from the link worked for me!

I hope I helped you!

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to use pygame.image.load("./../../images/player/jumper-1.png") because the directory .. is reserved for parent directory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).