# Python Script to detect broken images

Tags: python, image, jpeg, python-imaging-library, python-3.6

I wrote a python script to detect broken images and count them, 
The problem in my script is it detects all the images and does not detect broken images. How to fix this. I refered :

[How to check if a file is a valid image file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889333/how-to-check-if-a-file-is-a-valid-image-file) for my code

My code

```
import os
from os import listdir
from PIL import Image
count=0
for filename in os.listdir('/Users/ajinkyabobade/Desktop/2'):
    if filename.endswith('.JPG'):
     try:
      img=Image.open('/Users/ajinkyabobade/Desktop/2'+filename)
      img.verify()
     except(IOError,SyntaxError)as e:
         print('Bad file  :  '+filename)
         count=count+1
         print(count)
```

Answer (score 11):

I have added another SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53470882/1052899) that extends the PIL solution to better detect broken images.
I also implemented this solution in my Python script [here on GitHub](https://github.com/ftarlao/check-media-integrity).

I also verified that damaged files (jpg) frequently are not 'broken' images i.e, a damaged picture file sometimes remains a legit picture file, the original image is lost or altered but you are still able to load it.

I quote the other answer for completeness:

You can use Python *Pillow*(PIL) module, with most image formats, to check if a file is a valid and intact image file.

In the case you aim at detecting also broken images, @Nadia Alramli correctly suggests the `im.verify()` method, but this **does not detect all the possible image defects**, e.g., `im.verify` does not detect truncated images (that most viewer often load with a greyed area).

*Pillow* is able to detect these type of defects too, but you have to apply image manipulation or image decode/recode in or to trigger the check. Finally I suggest to use this code:

```
try:
  im = Image.load(filename)
  im.verify() #I perform also verify, don't know if he sees other types o defects
  im.close() #reload is necessary in my case
  im = Image.load(filename) 
  im.transpose(PIL.Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
  im.close()
except: 
  #manage excetions here
```

In case of image defects this code will raise an exception.
Please consider that im.verify is about 100 times faster than performing the image manipulation (and I think that flip is one of the cheaper transformations).
With this code you are going to verify a set of images at about 10 MBytes/sec (modern 2.5Ghz x86_64 CPU).

For the other formats *psd*,*xcf*,.. you can use *Imagemagick* wrapper *Wand*, the code is as follows:

```
im = wand.image.Image(filename=filename)
temp = im.flip;
im.close()
```

But, from my experiments Wand does not detect truncated images, I think it loads lacking parts as greyed area without prompting.

I red that *Imagemagick* has an external command *identify* that **could** make the job, but I have not found a way to invoke that function programmatically and I have not tested this route.

I suggest to always perform a preliminary check, check the *filesize* to not be zero (or very small), is a very *cheap* idea:

```
statfile = os.stat(filename)
filesize = statfile.st_size
if filesize == 0:
  #manage here the 'faulty image' case
```

Comment: Update for newer version of PIL: After `im = Image.open(...)`, instead of the transpose operation, use `im.load()`. This also catches that truncated image exception and seems to be faster than executing an actual image transformation.

Comment: I'll check this and update my script in case, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are building a bad path with

```
img=Image.open('/Users/ajinkyabobade/Desktop/2'+filename)
```

Try the following instead (by adding / to the end of the directory path)

```
img=Image.open('/Users/ajinkyabobade/Desktop/2/'+filename)
```

or

```
img=Image.open(os.path.join('/Users/ajinkyabobade/Desktop/2', filename))
```

Comment: This helped me in specifying the path, however, I do not get any bad file in output. I have added bad files to folder 2 to check that (by bad file I mean files which have extension .jpg but cannot be opened on pc)

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot be opened"?  If I copy a python file and give it a .jpg extension when it is checked I get "cannot identify image file" if I print out the exception.  Can you try that?

Comment: Thank you by cannot be opened I mean the following  "The file 2-10580.jpg could not be opened: It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize.". I found out the error: I was saving the file with extension .jpg but in python, I have filename.ends('.JPG') (all caps). Your solution solved the problem  I would highly appreciate if you could let me know how to autoconvert capital .JPG extension into small .jpg extension in folder2 using python script

Comment: .JPG is a valid extension.  You can catch both by using `if filename.upper().endswith('.JPG')`

Comment: quick question how do I delete these broken images?

Comment: Asked and answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996603/how-to-delete-a-file-or-folder

Answer (score 1):

try the below: It worked fine for me. It identifies the bad/corrupted image and remove them as well. Or if you want you can only print the bad/corrupted file name and remove the final script to delete the file.

```
for filename in listdir('/Users/ajinkyabobade/Desktop/2/'):
    if filename.endswith('.JPG'):
        try:
            img = Image.open('/Users/ajinkyabobade/Desktop/2/'+filename)  # open the image file
            img.verify()  # verify that it is, in fact an image
        except (IOError, SyntaxError) as e:
            print(filename)
            os.remove('/Users/ajinkyabobade/Desktop/2/'+filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am getting an error that tells me that `Image.load` is not available.   `Image.open` appears to work.

I was also getting errors using:

```
except (IOError, SyntaxError) as e:
```

I just changed that to:

```
except:
```

and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't see my solution here so will post it. Worked for my corrupted images, but good to check your usecase.

```
from cv2 import error 
import cv2

image= cv2.imread('your image')
try:
    cv2.imshow('image', image)
except error:
    print("error occured, now you can do some processing")
```