# Check If Image URL Leads To Real Image in Python

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, httprequest, urlrequest

**So I am building a Python script to download images from a list of urls.** The script works to an extent. I don't want it to download images that have urls that don't exist. I take care of a few images with some usage of status code but still get bad images. **I still get many images that I don't want.** Like these:

[image: bad image]
[image]

**Here is my code:**

```
import os
import requests
import shutil
import random
import urllib.request

def sendRequest(url):
    try:
        page = requests.get(url, stream = True, timeout = 1)

    except Exception:
        print('error exception')
        pass

    else:
        #HERE IS WHERE I DO THE STATUS CODE
        print(page.status_code)
        if (page.status_code == 200):
            return page

    return False

def downloadImage(imageUrl: str, filePath: str):
    img = sendRequest(imageUrl)

    if (img == False):
        return False

    with open(filePath, "wb") as f:
        img.raw.decode_content = True

        try:
            shutil.copyfileobj(img.raw, f)
        except Exception:
            return False

    return True

os.chdir('/Users/nikolasioannou/Desktop')
os.mkdir('folder')

fileURL = 'http://www.image-net.org/api/text/imagenet.synset.geturls?wnid=n04122825'
data = urllib.request.urlopen(fileURL)

output_directory = '/Users/nikolasioannou/Desktop/folder'

line_count = 0

for line in data:
    img_name = str(random.randrange(0, 10000)) + '.jpg'
    image_path = os.path.join(output_directory, img_name)
    downloadImage(line.decode('utf-8'), image_path)
    line_count = line_count + 1
#print(line_count)
```

Thanks for your time. Any ideas are appreciated.

Sincerely,
Nikolas

Comment: you could check for the jpeg or png header and magic sequence

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Sorry, I am fairly new to Python, how could I do this? @juliusmh

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a file is a valid image file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889333/how-to-check-if-a-file-is-a-valid-image-file)

Comment: Is the problem that you're getting non-images like an HTML page, or that you're getting useless placeholder images?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could check for the jpeg or png header and their respective magic sequence which is always a pretty good indicator for a valid image. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889333/how-to-check-if-a-file-is-a-valid-image-file) so question.

You can take al look at file signatures (aka magic numbers) [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures). You then just have to check the firs `n` bytes of `response.raw`

I modified your sendRequest/download function a little bit, you should be able to hardcode more valid image file extensions than just the JPG magic number. I finally tested the code and it is working (on my machine). Only valid JPG images were saved. Note that i removed the stream=True flag because the images are so small you don't need to have a stream. And the saving gets a little bit less cryptic. Take a look:

```
def sendRequest(url):
    try:
        page = requests.get(url)

    except Exception as e:
        print("error:", e)
        return False

    # check status code
    if (page.status_code != 200):
        return False

    return page

def downloadImage(imageUrl: str, filePath: str):
    img = sendRequest(imageUrl)

    if (img == False):
        return False

    if not img.content[:4] == b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0': return False

    with open(filePath, "wb") as f:
        f.write(img.content)

    return True
```

You could also try to open the image using Pillow and BytesIO

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> from io import BytesIO

>>> i = Image.open(BytesIO(img.content))
```

and see if it throws an error. But the first solution seems more lightweight - you should not get any false positives there. You could also check for the string `"<html>"` in `im.content` and abort if it was found - this is very easy and probably very effective too.

Comment: How do I check for a header and its respective magic sequence? I looked at the linked question and didnt understand much. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I guess where I'm confused is what do the file signatures do? What are they going to tell me about an image file and how do I know which file signature I should look for for an image with a false url?

Comment: basically you have no idea what the server responds or id the url is not existing anymore and so on. So files like JPEG or PNG images have a constant defined series of bytes to start with so an application can detect the file type without relying on the extension. You problem is not about the url. You have a bunch of bytes that you just downloaded, and you want to check if this bunch of bytes is an image. I update my question for the signature check.

Comment: Oh i seem, @juliusmh. thanks for the explanation. Ill check out the answer

Comment: Glad it helped, just comment if you need additional help. This sounds like a common problem maybe there is a library or so or you could bundle those signatures with a check function into a small library, would be good practice too! There is one more way to check if the bytes are a valid image: you could try to load the image using Pillow and BytesIO

Comment: im sorry to sound so helpless but i tried this code above by just replacing my old download function and every downloaded image gave the err "The file “name.jpg” could not be opened because it is empty." upon opening it. Also I am not sure what you were referring to above when you said "hardcode more valid image file extensions"

Comment: Ah god i made a mistake, the updated solution should work now? Hopefully :)

Comment: Thanks, ill give it a try