# firebase storage: strange filenames ending with slash

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, gcloud, gsutil

I've came across a very strange issue with firebase storage. One of our users manages to create files ending with slash:

[image: file ending with slash:]

He claims that he uses only web console, etc and doesn't do anything special. If I try to copy such file using gsutil I (obviously) get the following error:

Copying images/20610/...
Skipping attempt to download to filename ending with slash
(images/20610/). This
typically happens when using gsutil to download from a subdirectory
created by the Cloud Console (https://cloud.google.com/console)

Extended attributes do not show anything unusual except that this is indeed a file with a slash at the and in its filename:

```
    Creation time:          Mon, 27 Apr 2020 16:32:12 GMT
    Update time:            Mon, 27 Apr 2020 16:32:12 GMT
    Storage class:          STANDARD
    Content-Length:         11
    Content-Type:           text/plain
    Hash (crc32c):          XkI+Dw==
    Hash (md5):             apnFdauH+MfR7R5S5+NJzg==
    ETag:                   CL7wy46EiekCEAE=
    Generation:             1588005132499006
    Metageneration:         1
```

My question basically is - how is it possible? and what to do to prevent this?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Just implement a check to see if its an image, and furthermore, check the file type. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889333/how-to-check-if-a-file-is-a-valid-image-file this might hep

Answer (score 0):

You'll get an object with a trailing slash in the name if you create a folder using the Cloud Console.

Comment: well, If you look at the screenshot closely - that object is not a folder, but a file with a slash in it's name.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that before.
GCS doesn't have restrictions on whether object names end with a "/"; it's a client choice whether to permit that, and how to interpret objects named that way. gsutil and the Cloud Console (which are clients) won't allow creating objects that end with "/". Are you certain your user didn't use some other client to create the object?

Comment: I can't be a 100% positive, but I've asked directly a few times and the user confirmed that he uses only standard web based cloud console...