# Check if file from incoming request is an image

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm working on an application in which I need to upload images to an S3 bucket. The images come from HTTP requests inside *form data*s. I upload the images directly to S3 as objects (https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object), without saving them on my backend for security purposes.
But for other security purposes, is there a way to check if my image object is actually representing an image before uploading it to S3?

Comment: If you read the images via HTTP maybe you can look at the content-type HTTP header and see if it point to image?

Comment: Ignoring AWS and S3, how would you do this normally? What makes a file an "image", without actually trying to parse the file itself? Would you be willing to trust the Content Type?

Comment: Content-type has no valuable information whether the file is actually an image or no. @JohnRotenstein That's exactly my question, is there a way to know if a variable represents an image?

Comment: [python - How to check if a file is a valid image file? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889333/how-to-check-if-a-file-is-a-valid-image-file)

Answer (score 0):

Given a bytes object, the following solution worked out for me:

```
def validate_image(bytes_object):
    import io
    from PIL import Image
    try:
        Image.open(io.BytesIO(bytes_array))
    except OSError:
        print('Not a valid image')
```